# IP Link keeps resetting to down

Tags: linux, networking, centos

Recently I moved a server (Linux centos 6.5) to a new server. I don't know about the hardware I don't own the servers. However, when I did that(I've noticed this on linux in general with VMs and more lately) that the `eth0` in `ip link show` will change to higher numbers.

I went in and named `eth0` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` to `ifcfg-eth2`. I had issues with ip link set `eth0` name `eth2` and the connection would still drop.

Just now I had to go in an do ip link set eth2 up because the link went down.

How do I prevent the links from going down? What is causing this? How do I properly fix this problem.

I noticed under `ifconfig` when I brought it up there are over 400000000000 errors.

EDIT:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2
DEVICE="eth2"
BOOTPROTO=none
#BROADCAST="108.x.x.135"
DNS1="208.x.x.22"
GATEWAY="108.x.x.129"
IPADDR="108.x.x.130"
NETMASK="255.255.255.248"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT="yes"
DNS2=64.x.x.82
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no

cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# PCI device 0x8086:0x10d3 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:25:90:4c:e0:ad", ATTR{type}=="1",                                  KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

# PCI device 0x8086:0x10d3 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:25:90:4c:e0:ac", ATTR{type}=="1",                                  KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x8086:0x10d3 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:25:90:75:ad:69", ATTR{type}=="1",                                  KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"

# PCI device 0x8086:0x10d3 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:25:90:75:ad:68", ATTR{type}=="1", 

                             KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth3"
```

I've wuped the .rules file. I've set everything to eth0 and ip link show will show UP and ifconfig will show the eth0 device but it will still randomly drop connectivity out of the blue.

Comment: Can you ensure that the flag 'NM_CONTROLLED' is set to 'no' and try again?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'll post full config

Comment: Does this network interface have a consistently named MAC address?

Comment: That I am not sure of. How do I properly set the MAC Address?

Comment: Well, you normally dont set it, you can but on a typical host the MAC address will be consistent between boots. Is this the case here?

Comment: How can I tell if it is? Would I reboot the server several times and then check it in ifconfig?

Comment: Check `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and see if you have multiple declarations in there with different MAC addresses.

Comment: Updated. It looks like there are many.

Comment: Is this a real machine or a VM?

Comment: I've seen the issue happen on both when moving hardware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think you can rename the network interface in that way

```
from http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L1143
```

linux kernel uses struct net_device for define the net interface, if interface is referenced in some where that means the interface is used and rename without put the interface down isn't good idea

Comment: Since the kernel actualy is keeping track of network objects via their ifindex value, I doubt that what you name it has any real significance.

Comment: i'm connected in console, linux-80kc:~ # ip link set eth1 name eth0
RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy , so i think linux has some referenced to know if the interface is used

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Wipe /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules (delete all the contents)
- Make sure you have only one /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth* file, and name it /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
- Reboot

I suspect you've migrated machines here, while saving your old persistent-net file.  This appears to be causing some significant confusion.

Comment: Tried that. It still randomly decides to drop network connectivity for some reason.

Comment: Can you post your updated persistent-net file?  Does that still have 4 MACs?

Answer (score 0):

To rename network interfaces:

Check network interface hardware address: **lspci -D |grep Ethernet**
Check motherboard model: **dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name**

Our file **/etc/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-net.rules** on LTE LabKit

[yatebts@ybts-UNCONFIG ~]$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-net.rules

```
# motherboard Gigabyte Z370N WIFI-CF                                                                                                                                                                              
# 0000:00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V was enp0s31f6                                                                                           
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNELS=="0000:00:1f.6", NAME:="eth-ran"

# 0000:05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03) was enp5s0
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNELS=="0000:05:00.0", NAME:="eth-mgmt"
```

[yatebts@ybts-UNCONFIG ~]$

Answer (score 0):

To keep the IP up even if the link gets down ([2938737.731632] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Link is down)

If the interface has a static IP (OR does not get the IP from a dhcp server)
Edit /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
add: **MII_NOT_SUPPORTED=yes** and **ACCOUNTING=no**